# How can I get ObjectURL as a response in aws S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a audio file in AWS s3 bucket .I tried to access the bucket using nodejs and I got details of the response but I'm not getting the objectURL as a response from the object.I'm getting other info such as key,ETag,body,contentLength.How can I get objectURl

Comment: Could you provide your current code?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no special API to get the Object URL, you can just construct it yourself. It has [well defined format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html#virtual-host-style-url-ex):

```
https://<bucket-name>.s3.<Region>.amazonaws.com/<key-name>
```

Comment: Yeh I do get a objectURl in aws s3 website.But  when I try to access the object from the nodejs like a get request I dont get objectURl as a prop.PLs let me know if we can get that by some method

Comment: @Nanda Hi. If you know the bucket name, region and the name/key of the object, you just construct the url yourself using the format specified in the answer.